# Why doesn't std::queue::pop return value.?

Tags: c++, stl

I went through this [page](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/queue.html#3) but I am not able to get the reason for the same . There it is mentioned that

> "it is more sensible for it to return no value at all and to require
> clients to use front() to inspect the value at the front of the queue"

But inspecting an element from front() also required that element to be copied in lvalue. For example in this code segment

```
std::queue<int> myqueue;
int myint;
int result;
std::cin >> myint;
myqueue.push (myint);
/* here temporary will be created on RHS which will be assigned to
   result, and in case if returns by reference then result will be
   rendered invalid after pop operation */
result = myqueue.front();  //result.
std::cout << ' ' << result;
myqueue.pop();
```

on fifth line *cout* object first creates a copy of myqueue.front() then assigns that to result. So, whats the difference, pop function could have done the same thing.

Comment: Because is implemented this way (i.e., `void std::queue::pop();`).

Comment: The question has been answered, but as a sidenote: if you really want a pop that returns, it can be easily implemented with a free function: http://ideone.com/lnUzf6

Comment: Your link is to the STL documentation. But you are asking about the C++ standard library. Different things.

Comment: "But inspecting an element from `front()` also required that element to be copied in lvalue" - no it doesn't. `front` returns a reference, not a value. You can inspect the value it refers to without copying it.

Comment: That's a dupe, and IIRC even of one of the FAQ questions. (I'm currently on mobile and can't search for it, though.)

Comment: My concern was the pop will invalidate the reference returned by front().  I have a very large value_type and trying to implement efficient multithreading code. I need to get a lock first, then get a reference to the value on the queue, pop the element from the queue, release the lock so that the producer can push onto the queue and my code can consume the large value outside the critical section. I guess this is not possible. Any comment.

Comment: @KeminZhou the model you describe requires a copy. Maybe. If you want to multiplex consumption of the queue then yes, you must make a copy before releasing the lock on the queue. However, if you only care about separating input and output, then you don't _need_ a lock to inspect the front. You could wait to lock until you are done consuming it and need to call `pop()`. If you use `std::queue<T, std::list<T>>` then there is no concern about the reference provided from `front()` being invalidated by a `push()`. But you must *know* your usage pattern and should document your constraints.

Comment: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/queue.html#3 is a dead link. Does anyone know a proper home?

Comment: I solved my problem by using C++11 move, unique_lock<mutex> lk(mut); LargeVal x=std::move(myqueue.front()). myqueue.pop(); lk.unlock(); // consume LargeVal.  This pattern may be useful to others.  This saves the cost of copying.  I tested in my multithreading code, and it seems to work well.

Comment: the real reason: compilers used to suck. we didn't have move semantics, noexcept & copy-elision. now we do, and besides all the nonsense you can read below, we could have an API that does this correctly and safely, but it's too late to change...

Comment: @jwm http://web.archive.org/web/20140716110236/http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/queue.html is probably the version of the page that existed when this question was posted.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

> So, whats the difference, pop function could have done the same thing.

It could indeed have done the same thing. The reason it didn't, is because a pop that returned the popped element is unsafe in the presence of exceptions (having to return by value and thus creating a copy).

Consider this scenario (with a naive/made up pop implementation, to ilustrate my point):

```
template<class T>
class queue {
    T* elements;
    std::size_t top_position;
    // stuff here
    T pop()
    {
        auto x = elements[top_position];
        // TODO: call destructor for elements[top_position] here
        --top_position;  // alter queue state here
        return x;        // calls T(const T&) which may throw
    }
```

If the copy constructor of T throws on return, you have already altered the state of the queue (`top_position` in my naive implementation) and the element is removed from the queue (and not returned). For all intents and purposes (no matter how you catch the exception in client code) the element at the top of the queue is lost.

This implementation is also inefficient in the case when you do not need the popped value (i.e. it creates a copy of the element that nobody will use).

This can be implemented safely and efficiently, with two separate operations (`void pop` and `const T& front()`).

Comment: C++11 note: if T has a cheap noexcept move-constructor (which is often the case for the kind of objects put in stacks) then returning by value is efficient and exception-safe.

Comment: @RomanL: If the suggestion is that the signature of the function should change depending on the type that is contianed in the stack... that would be surprising at the very least. I don't see a problem with the current implementation (for the single threaded case) and I see no point in complicating the specification and implementations.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I'm not suggesting any changes, my point was that some of the mentioned drawbacks become less of an issue with C++11.

Comment: But why is it called `pop`? that is quite counter-intuitive. It could be named `drop`, and then it's clear for everyone that it doesn't pop the element, but drops it instead...

Comment: "pop" in this context means exactly that it drops an element. The names push and pop are the de-facto names for these operations and have been since the '70s. If the operation was named differently, it would cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: @utnapistim: the de-facto "pop" operation has always been to take the top element from a stack and return it. When I first came across STL stacks I was surprised, to say the least, about `pop` not returning anything. See for example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#Array).

Comment: @RomanL : From C++11, we have move constructor supported and hence, copy constructor will not be called while returning the popped element by values. So, if top and pop are combined into a single function, will there be still exception ?

Answer (score 50):

The page you have linked to answers your question.

To quote the whole section relevant:

> One might wonder why pop() returns void, instead of value_type. That is, why must one use front() and pop() to examine and remove the element at the front of the queue, instead of combining the two in a single member function? In fact, there is a good reason for this design. If pop() returned the front element, it would have to return by value rather than by reference: return by reference would create a dangling pointer. Return by value, however, is inefficient: it involves at least one redundant copy constructor call. Since it is impossible for pop() to return a value in such a way as to be both efficient and correct, it is more sensible for it to return no value at all and to require clients to use front() to inspect the value at the front of the queue.

C++ is designed with efficiency in mind, over the number of lines of code the programmer has to write.

Comment: Perhaps, but the real reason is that it is impossible to implement an exception safe version (with the strong guarantee) for a version of `pop` which returns a value.

Answer (score 7):

pop cannot return a reference to the value that is removed, as it is being removed from the data structure, so what should the reference refer to? It could return by value, but what if the result of pop is not stored anywhere? Then time is wasted copying the value unnecessarily.

Comment: The real reason is exception safety. There is no safe way to have a "transaction" with the stack (either the element stays on the stack, or it's returned to you) if `pop` returns and the act of returning can result in an exception. It would obviously have to remove the element before it returns it, and then if something throws the element might be irrevocably lost.

Comment: Does this concern still apply with f.i. a noexcept move constructor? (Of course 0 copies are more efficient that two moves, but that could open the door for an exception safe, efficent combined front+pop)

Comment: @peppe, you could return by value if you know the `value_type` has a nothrow move constructor, but the queue interface would then be different depending on what type of object you store in it, which would not be helpful.

Comment: @peppe: That would be safe, but stack is a generic library class and therefore the more it has to assume about the element type the less useful it is.

Comment: I know the STL wouldn't allow for that, but that means one can build his own queue class with blackjack and ^W^W^W with this feature :)

Comment: Then how come other languages return the value removed from pop?

Comment: @user3932000 It's not impossible to design it that way, it's just not what C++ does.

Answer (score 4):

With the current implementation, this is valid:

```
int &result = myqueue.front();
std::cout << result;
myqueue.pop();
```

If pop would return a reference, like this:

```
value_type& pop();
```

Then the following code could crash, since the reference is not valid anymore:

```
int &result = myqueue.pop();
std::cout << result;
```

On the other hand, if it would return a value directly:

```
value_type pop();
```

Then you would need to do a copy for this code to work, which is less efficient:

```
int result = myqueue.pop();
std::cout << result;
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting from C++11 it would possible to archive desired behavior using move semantics. Like `pop_and_move`. So copy constructor will not be called, and  performance will depend on move constructor only.

Comment: No, move semantics does not magically make `pop` exception safe.

Comment: @L.F. It almost certainly does. It's really, really, really hard to imagine a reasonable class with a move-constructor that throws, Still, given that this is a template, committee could have designed a new function that is enabled conditionally. And finally put a stop to an awful, boilerplate and bug-prone path of making a **two** calls to do a **one** thing.

Comment: Agreed. And for the paranoid among us, we could enable it only when certain exception guarantees are met. You can always roll your own algorithm. Here's a free function that does what you probably want: `template <typename T, typename Container>
[[nodiscard]] std::optional<T> pop(std::queue<T, Container>& queue) noexcept(noexcept(std::optional<T>{std::move(std::declval<T&>())}) && std::is_nothrow_destructible_v<T>);` https://godbolt.org/z/vhPx1YnjW

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do this:

```
std::cout << ' ' << myqueue.front();
```

Or, if you want the value in a variable, use a reference:

```
const auto &result = myqueue.front();
if (result > whatever) do_whatever();
std::cout << ' ' << result;
```

Next to that: the wording 'more sensible' is a subjective form of 'we looked into usage patterns and found more need for a split'.  (Rest assured: the C++ language is not evolving lightly...)