# Why C++ Standard Library Stack's implemented pop() without returning a value?

Tags: c++, stack, std

I believe that the standard C++ library always prioritize performance, but why did they implemented the stack pop() without returning a value?

This way we need to call top() to get the value and then pop(), calling 2 functions -double of the overhead of a function call-.

**- Is there a specific reason why they choose to implement it this way or was it just an arbitrary choice?**

**EDIT:** I'm just leaving this question here to help people who search for stacks instead of queues. There is an answer here which I believe that apply to both cases:

[Why doesn't std::queue::pop return value.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035691/why-stdqueuepop-doesnt-returns-value)