# Trying to create queue using stacks. Why am I getting a void to int conversion error?

Tags: c++, stack, queue

This is my first attempt at creating a queue using two stacks. I am not sure if I am on the right track because I have been unable to check my work due to an `'=': cannot convert from 'void' to 'int'` error. The error lies on this line: `x = enQ.pop();`. enQ is not a function, so how could it be void?

My code is not yet finished of course.

```
stack<int> enQ;
stack<int> deQ;

void enQueue(int x) {
    enQ.push(x);
    cout << x << " has been added to the queue." << endl;
}

void deQueue() {
    while (enQ.size() != 0) {
        int x;
        x = enQ.pop();
        enQ.pop();
        deQ.push(x);
        cout << x << " had been pushed to DEQUEUE" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `enQ.pop` is the function, and it has return type `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function [std::stack::pop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) returns nothing (i.e. its return type is `void`).

You could change

```
x = enQ.pop();
```

to

```
x = enQ.top();
enQ.pop();
```

Comment: Which proves Dr. Seuss was almost right. The correct answer is [Top on Pop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hop_on_Pop).

Answer (score 1):

You can check this post to see why STL separate the `T kind_of_pop_and_get()` into `pop` and `top`. Former only removes the top element on stack, and latter simply copying the top element without touching stack.

[Why doesn't std::queue::pop return value.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035691/why-doesnt-stdqueuepop-return-value)

In short, it is for **exception safety**.

The `kind_of_pop_and_get()` will do

- Remove element from stack.
- Then return the element to `copy assignment/constructor` of receiver.

Exception may throw during object construction and start the stack unwinding. Then the stack state could be affected even the `kind_of_pop_and_get()` call is not completed.