# I am getting "void value not ignored as it ought to be" what should i do?

Tags: c++, vector

**QUESTION LINK:**

> https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/minimize-the-absolute-difference/
>
> It has an ide so you can solve it on the website itself.

**QUESTION:**

Given three sorted arrays A, B and C of not necessarily same sizes.

Calculate the minimum absolute difference between the maximum and minimum number from the triplet a, b, c such that a, b, c belongs arrays A, B, C respectively.
i.e. minimize | max(a,b,c) - min(a,b,c) |.

Example :

Input:

```
A : [ 1, 4, 5, 8, 10 ]
B : [ 6, 9, 15 ]
C : [ 2, 3, 6, 6 ]
```

Output:

```
1
```

Explanation: We get the minimum difference for a=5, b=6, c=6 as | max(a,b,c) - min(a,b,c) | = |6-5| = 1.

**MY SOLUTION:**

```
int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B, vector<int> &C) {

    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,i,j;

    a=A.pop_back();
    b=B.pop_back();
    c=C.pop_back();

    while(A.size()>0 && B.size()>0 && C.size()>0){


        if(a>=b && b>=c){
            d = abs(a-c);
            if(d<f){
                f=d;
            }
            a=A.pop_back();
        }

        if(a>=b && c>=b){
            d = abs(a-b);
            if(d<f){
                f=d;
            }
            a=A.pop_back();
        }

        if(b>=a && a>=c){
            d = abs(b-c);
            if(d<f){
                f=d;
            }
            b=B.pop_back();
        }

        if(b>=a && c>=a){
            d = abs(b-a);
            if(d<f){
                f=d;
            }
            b=B.pop_back();
        }

        if(c>=a && a>=b){
            d = abs(c-b);
            if(d<f){
                f=d;
            }
            c=C.pop_back();
        }

        if(c>=b && b>=a){
            d = abs(c-a);
            if(d<f){
                f=d;
            }
            c=C.pop_back();
        }


    }

    cout<<f;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `pop_back()` function doesn't return the element popped. You have to do this:

```
a = A.back();
A.pop_back();
```

... and so on.

See [Why doesn't std::queue::pop return value.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035691/why-doesnt-stdqueuepop-return-value) for explanation of the API design.

Comment: @yogeshdhiman If this answer solved your problem, consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark