# How do I return a base class variable and delete it?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the first element in the list and remove it.

If I return the node (`ListNode*`) then I won't be able to remove it. If I remove it before I return, then there will be nothing to return because it will have already been removed.

I'm trying to keep the remove capability inside the function `getFirst()` instead of creating a separate `remove()` function. By creating a temp pointer, I will still run into the same problem (not being able to delete it). I have tried to implement the deletion and ignored the get part of the requirement.

```
ListNode* LinkedList::getFirst(){
    ListNode *nodePtr; //traverse the list
    if(head == nullptr){
        std::cout << "List is empty no node to remove"<< std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    else{
        nodePtr = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete nodePtr;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

How can I return the pointer and delete it?

Comment: Ideally, don't. See [Why doesn't std::queue::pop return value.?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25035691/10077)

Comment: What pointer are you trying to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is caused by trying to do too many things in the function.

Don't use `getFirst` to do anything other than "get the first node".

In addition, removing the first node from the linked list is different than deleting the first node of the linked list.

Here's my suggestion.

```
// Return the first node of the linked list.
ListNode* LinkedList::getFirst()
{
   return head;
}

// Remove the first node from the linked list.
void LinkedList::removeFirst()
{
   if(head != nullptr)
   {
      ListNode *nodePtr = head;
      head = head->next;

      delete nodePtr;
   }
}

// Detach the first node from the linked list and return the detached node.
LinkedNode* LinkedList::detachFirst()
{
   if(head == nullptr){
      return nullptr;
   }

   ListNode *nodePtr = head;
   head = head->next;

   return nodePtr;
}
```

Usage:

```
LinkedList l;

//
// Fill up the linked list with nodes.
//

ListNode* first = l.getFirst();
if ( first != nullptr )
{
   // Use the first node.
}

// Delete the first node from the linked list.
l.removeFirst();

// Detach the first node from the linked list.
ListNode* first = l.detachFirst();
if ( first != nullptr )
{
   // Use the first node.
   // ...

   // Then delete it.
   delete first;
}
```

Comment: This is the best idea.  Separate the responsibilities.  You could even go as far as making `removeFirst()` call `detachFirst()` so they can share common code, eg: `void LinkedList::removeFirst() { delete detachFirst(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Remove should not delete the object, it should only remove it from the list. You will have to delete it outside the list.

i.e.:

```
Node * list::get_head()
{
 if(!head)
return nullptr;
else
{
Node * ptr = head;
head = head->next;
ptr->next=mullptr;
return ptr;
}
}
```

and then:

```
list l;
Node * ptr = l.getFirst();
...
delete ptr
```

And note this is the sort of thing that are greatly improved by templates, you could make your node store data, take a copy of the data, delete the actual node and finally return the copied data.

Comment: And if someone calls `getFirst()` and forgets to `delete` the returned pointer, a memory leak occurs.  This is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return only the value of the node, you can try this:

```
int LinkedList::getFirst(){
    ListNode *nodePtr; //traverse the list
    int node_value;
    if(head == nullptr){
        std::cout << "List is empty no node to remove"<< std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    else{
        nodePtr = head;
        node_value = nodePtr->value;
        head = head->next;
        delete nodePtr;
    }

    return node_value;
}
```

Obviously, you have to change the return value of your function (I assume that is an integer).

Comment: `return nullptr;` will not work for an `int` return value, you would have to use `return 0;` instead. And what if there were an element with a value of 0? This is not a good idea.