# Compilation Error: void value not ignored as it ought to be in std::queue::pop()

Tags: c++, queue, std

Write a function to connect all the adjacent nodes at the same level in a binary tree. Structure of the given Binary Tree node is like following.

```
struct Node{
  int data;
  Node* left;
  Node* right;
  Node* nextRight; 
}
```

Initially, all the `nextRight` pointers point to garbage values. Your function should set these pointers to point next right for each node.

My code is

```
#include<queue>
/*
Please note that it's Function problem i.e.
you need to write your solution in the form of Function(s) only.
Driver Code to call/invoke your function would be added by GfG's Online Judge.*/


/* struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node *left,  *right;
  Node *nextRight;  // This has garbage value in input trees
}; */
// Should set the nextRight for all nodes
void connect(Node *p)
{
   Node *temp=p;
   queue<Node *> q;
   Node *pp=NULL;
   q.push(p);
   q.push(pp);
   while(q.empty()==false)
   {
       Node* nn=q.pop(); //  <---------- Error appears here
       Node* conn=NULL;
       if(nn!=NULL)
       {
           conn=q.front();
           nn->nextRight=conn;
           if(nn->left!=NULL)
               q.push(nn->left);
           if(nn->right!=NULL)
               q.push(nn->right);
       }
       else if(q.empty()==false)
       {
           q.push(pp);
       }

   }

}
```

It gives this error:

```
Compilation Error... 
prog.cpp: In function 'void connect(Node*)':
prog.cpp:120:23: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
        Node* nn=q.pop();
                       ^
```

Help me to run the code without this error.

Comment: [`std::queue::pop()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop) doesn't return a value, get it with `front()` before calling `pop()`.

Comment: Use `front()` to get value, `pop()` removes 1st element returning nothing http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop

Comment: Minimal example please. / Which part of the error message don't you understand? Everything? You need to learn basic C++.

Comment: What's not clear? You are calling a function that returns `void` (nothing) yet trying to store that return value as a `Node*`. How would you expect that to work?

Answer (score 2):

`std::queue`'s `pop` function doesn't return the popped element, it only removes the front element, so instead you first have to call `q.front()` and then call `q.pop()`.

```
Node* nn=q.pop();
```

becomes:

```
Node* nn=q.front();
q.pop();
```

If you want you can write a helper function like this:

```
template<class T>
auto popget(T& queue)
{
    auto ret = std::move(queue.front());
    queue.pop();

    return ret;
}
```

Then you can simply write your code this way:

```
Node* nn=popget(q);
```

Comment: `Node* nn=q.front();` creates a copy of the front, if it was `Node*& nn=q.front()` you'd be right @KillzoneKid

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you're right

Answer (score 0):

Your error is quite simple; STL based containers that have pop and push algorithms do not return the value during the pop. Thus, you have to call `std::queue::front()` (Or `back()`, depending on what you need) on the container to get the value before popping it. For more details, read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25035949/6525260).