# Writing pop() method for LinkedStack in O(1)

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, big-o

How would I write a `pop()` method for LinkedStack in O(1)?
I have two private data members in my `LinkedStack` class: `ListNode* head` and `ListNode* tail`.

`head` points to the beginning of the `LinkedStack`, and `tail` points to the end of the `LinkedStack`.

`pop()` will remove the `ListNode` being pointed to by `tail`, then `tail` will point to the `ListNode` that was **before** `tail`.

Knowing this, how would I write `pop()` in `O(1)`? Obviously, I can write a for loop that grabs the previous `ListNode` right before `tail`, but then `pop()` wouldn't be `O(1)`.

Since this is for homework, I'm not looking for code solutions, just maybe a hint in the right direction.

**Edit**: One solution I possibly see is having a `ListNode* prev` data member, which always points to the previous ListNode before `tail`. But I feel like there's a more efficient way....

**Edit2**: Thanks @user4581301. **Assume that `pop()` will not be called when `LinkedStack` is empty.**

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for mentioning that! Assume that pop will not be called when the linked list is empty.

Comment: O(1) solution (making some assumptions here): `ListNode* temp = tail; tail = tail->prev; delete temp;` If you can't do this, rethink your linked list logic because something is broken or overly complex. If you want to return what's at the node you have to do a bit more work. Note that the standard library's stack returns nothing from `pop` to avoid this extra work and some of the nastiness that comes with it. [Link to related question that covers some of the nastiness.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035691/why-doesnt-stdqueuepop-return-value)

Comment: Jeeze. My apologies. I wasn't even thinking singly-linked list. Yes, what you were trying to do with tail was not possible, probably why my brain filtered it out and assumed doubly linked list. I should have read your question edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you state, *any* situation where you have to traverse the list to locate a specific element is going to make the constant time requirement impossible to meet. This includes a singly-linked list where you're pushing items on to the end. A *doubly-linked* list will be easier since you can then get from the tail to the penultimate item without traversal.

However, I'm not sure *why* you're pushing on to the end. If you were to push new elements on the the *front* of the list, achieving constant time for both `push` and `pop` is trivial.

By that, I mean (pseudo-code since, as you mention, "this is for homework"):

```
def push(x):
    allocate node          # get new node and set data.
    node.data = x

    node.next = head       # insert at head of list
    head = node

def pop():
    assert head != null    # catch pop on empty stack

    node = head            # get first node and data
    retval = node.data

    head = head.next       # set head to be second node

    free node              # free node and return data
    return retval
```

You can see that there is no traversal of the list for either operation. First, pushing `7` on to a stack of primes:

```
Starting list:
    head
        \
         5 -> 3 -> 2 -|

Create new node, point to current head:
     head
         \
     7 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -|

Point head at new node:
    head
        \
         7 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -|
```

Now let's pop that same value.

```
Starting list:
    head
        \
         7 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -|

Save head as node, and value to return (7):
    head
        \
         7 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -|
        /
    node

Adjust head:
         head
             \
         7 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -|
        /
    node

Free node and return stored value (7):
    head
        \
         5 -> 3 -> 2 -|
```