# Invalid use of void expression with a Queue and .pop()

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to make it so that I can pop elements from one queue into a new queue and keep getting that error for this first line of code "temp.push(Q.pop());".

It is something fundamental I am missing so can it be pointed out?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void Halves(queue<int>& Q)
{
    stack<int> reverse;
    queue<int> temp;
    for (int i=0; i < Q.size()/2 ; i++)
    {
        temp.push(Q.pop());
    }
    for (int i=0; i < Q.size(); i++)
    {
        reverse.push(Q.pop());
    }
    for (int i=0; i < reverse.size(); i++)
    {
        Q.push(reverse.pop());
    }
    for (int i=0; i < temp.size(); i++)
    {
        Q.push(temp.pop());
    }
    copy(Q);
}
```

Comment: Here's a reference for [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue). And that site is good in general. You may consult it every time you need a standard library reference.

Comment: *"It is something fundamental I am missing..."* - Yes. Read the documentation of the classes and their members you're using. It is somewhat folly to use them otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't std::queue::pop return value.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035691/why-doesnt-stdqueuepop-return-value)

Comment: Not 100% exact, but explains it in much more depth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of [`std::queue::pop()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop) is `void`. Hence, you may not use:

```
reverse.push(Q.pop());
```

You can use:

```
reverse.push(Q.front());
Q.pop();
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::queue::pop()` does not return the popped element.

To access the to be popped element use `std::queue::front()`