# Assign first item of queue to int

Tags: c++, int, queue

I am trying to assign the first item of a queue to an int

```
queue<int> q;
int cur = q.pop();
```

put it gives me an error

```
Types 'int' and 'void' are not compatible
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue

Comment: Yes - `pop` [has no return value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop). Before you use the queue you should read up on its interface.

Comment: en.cppreference.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't std::queue::pop return value.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035691/why-doesnt-stdqueuepop-return-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to read the documentation, that would have told you

```
queue<int> q;
...
int cur = q.front();
q.pop();
```