# return the value of the deleted node

Tags: c++

```
int dequeueAndReturnValue()
{
    if (front==NULL)
        cout << "There is no items to vomit" << endl;
    else
    {
        Node*ptr = front;
        front = front->next;
        delete ptr;
    }
}
```

I want to return the value of the deleted pointer from a method called int

Comment: store result before deletion ?

Comment: A note: it's hard to make a safe `dequeueAndReturnValue` function. This is why it is rarely offered. More on that: [Why doesn't std::queue::pop return value.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035691/why-doesnt-stdqueuepop-return-value)

Comment: What do you mean with _the value of the deleted node_?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 std::unique_ptr<Node> ptr( front );
 front = ptr->next;
 return ptr->value;
```

but you should actually use smart pointers in the first place.

Note: in case `front` is equal to `nullptr` (and you should use it instead of `NULL`) you must return something as well or throw an exception, otherwise your code would have Undefined Behaviour.