# C++ Linked List with template - How to create pop()?

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I've created a linked list with the template `Fifo` in C++, and I want to create the method `pop()` but it doesn't work.

My methods should do these following tasks:
`pop()` should read the first `FifoElement`'s `value` then delete it.
`operator>>` should do the same thing.

`push()` should create an copy of T Object into Fifo.
`operator<<` should do the same like `push()`.

When I compile, I get the following error:
`request for member 'value' in '((Fifo<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*)this)->Fifo<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::temp', which is of pointer type 'Fifo<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::FifoElement*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)`

My Class:

```
#include "Fifo.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
Fifo<T>::Fifo(){
    top = NULL;
    last = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
Fifo<T>::~Fifo(){
}

template <typename T>
Fifo<T>& Fifo<T>::operator<<(T const& val){
    Fifo::push(val);

    Fifo::s++;
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
Fifo<T>& Fifo<T>::operator>>(T& val){
    Fifo::pop();
}

template <typename T>
Fifo<T>::operator int() const{
    return s;
}

template <typename T>
void Fifo<T>::push(const T& val){
   FifoElement *temp = new FifoElement;

   temp->value=val;
   temp->next=NULL;

   if(top==NULL){
    top=temp;
    last=temp;
    temp=NULL;
   }

   else{
    last->next=temp;
    last=temp;
   }
}

template<typename T>
T Fifo<T>::pop(){

    temp=top;
    top=top->next;
    return temp.value; //here I'm getting an error! 
    delete temp;
}

template<typename T>
int size(){
    return Fifo<T>::s;
}

template<typename T>
int info(){
    return Fifo<T>::s;
}
```

My header:

```
#ifndef FIFO_H
#define FIFO_H

template <typename T>
class Fifo
{
    public:
        Fifo();
        ~Fifo();
        void push(const T& val);
        T pop();
        Fifo& operator<<(T const& val);
        Fifo& operator>>(T& val);
        operator int() const;
        int size();
        int info();


    private:
        //Packet FifoElement
        struct FifoElement{
            T value;
            FifoElement* next;
        };

        FifoElement* top;
        FifoElement* last;
        FifoElement* temp;
        int s;
};

#endif // FIFO_H
```

Comment: [The trick with pop is you can't safely return a value and pop at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035691/why-doesnt-stdqueuepop-return-value). Being asked to write a function to do it is kind of disingenuous. Fortunately, the first answer to the linked question shows how to do it unsafely so you can continue on your way and pass your class or whatever.

Comment: Please show the contents of `#include "Fifo.h"` and describe the problem with the current code in detail. Your comment in the code says `//here I'm getting an error!`, but you never gave the actual error message. Please copy-paste the exact error message. What is particularly weird to me (without seeing the header contents) is that `temp` does not seem to be declared anywhere. Surely a temporary variable would not be a member of the `Fifo` class, right? That would be counter to the intention of something being temporary.

Comment: Side note: You cannot `delete` after a `return`. You can't do anything after a `return`. The function has exited and no further code in the function will be executed. This may-or-may not be the unknown error you mention in your comments.

Comment: Consider using a different data structure than a linked list. With modern systems it's a horribly badly performing thing. In *most* cases, a `std::vector` would be a better choice.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is clearly some sort of assignment, otherwise there would be no point in implementing this yourself in the first place.

Comment: @uneven_mark People reimplement basic things *all the time*, for no reason. Don't underestimate the "not invented here" syndrome.

Comment: I added the header file. I'm new to C++ and my next chapter is to learn how to use pointers, so my exercise is to create an Linked List without STL.

Comment: @uneven_mark how should it look then?

Comment: Please define "doesn't want to work." Otherwise, we can't really help you effectively and answer your question.

Comment: @Chipster I get this error: request for member 'value' in '((Fifo<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*)this)->Fifo<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::temp', which is of pointer type 'Fifo<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::FifoElement*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|

Comment: @Coder95 If you want to access members of a class instance through a pointer to that class instance, you need to use `->` instead of `.` in the member access syntax. That should have been covered when pointers were introduced earlier in the book.

Comment: @JaMiT Ups.. Yes, I meant my pop() method doesn't work. My expected outcome should be the value.. :)

Comment: Concerning your question, there's another thing: You need a [mcve]. In particular, you need to find out whether the template part has an influence or not. Also, read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Why all the manual memory management? Use smart pointers and/or containers. Manual `new` / `delete` is a code smell in modern C++ (almost always).

Answer (score 1):

From the Comments, the error you get is this:

> 'value' in '((Fifo >*)this)->Fifo >::temp', which is of pointer type 'Fifo >::FifoElement*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|

The error kind of says the problem.

The problem is `temp` is a pointer. Pointers can't use the `.` syntax. You either need to dereference it (`*`) first like this:

```
(*temp).value
```

Or, even better, use the arrow (`->`) notation, just as it says:

```
temp->value
```

---

Your code has a few problems with it, and while I answered the one you asked about specifically, here are a few more problems with your code that you fight want to fix.

First, your `pop()` function:

```
//...
return temp->value;
delete temp;
```

You can't execute any code after you `return` something. Thus, you have a memory leak. Instead, do this:

```
//...
T result = temp->value;
delete temp;
return result;
```

This will avoid memory leaks in your `pop()` function.

While we're on the subject of memory leaks, you also have another one, though:

```
template <typename T>
Fifo<T>::~Fifo(){
}
```

Your destructor does nothing, which will cause a memory leak once your list goes out of scope. I would much rather leave how to properly implement it as an exercise for you, but just know that you need to delete everything in your list.

Next, let's talk about `operator<<()`:

```
template <typename T>
Fifo<T>& Fifo<T>::operator<<(T const& val){
    Fifo::push(val);

    Fifo::s++;
    return *this;
}
```

This should work fine, but `s++` probably shouldn't be here. `push()` should manage the size. If it doesn't then you should add it. This is because `push()` can get called directly. If it does, then the `s` variable could get corrupted (that is, it won't match the actual size).

If `push()` does manage it, then you shouldn't modify it in the `operator<<()`, because that would make the size get increased twice, also making the `s` variable not match the actual size.

Finally, `operator<<()`:

```
template <typename T>
Fifo<T>& Fifo<T>::operator>>(T& val){
    Fifo::pop();
}
```

This is problematic, because you don't actually set `val`. You just `pop()` the stack and discard its value.

Here's how it should look:

```
template <typename T>
Fifo<T>& Fifo<T>::operator>>(T& val){
    val = pop();

    return *this; // don't forget to return the list like you stated in your function declaration
}
```