# How to pass the element from STL queue to a function?

Tags: c++, recursion, stl, queue

My queue is of type `queue<string>`. I am pushing the possible combinations of an 8-piece puzzle problem to be explored later by BFS method. I am using simply `obj.push(possible_string)`. I am supposed to call this function recursively that pushes possible moves to find other possible combinations (next possible moves).

I’ve tried `myfunc(obj.pop())` and `myfunc(&obj.pop())` for recursion and dequeuing which does not work!

What could be the get around?

Comment: `pop()` function returns void so you can't get an element using it.

Comment: @ArtemBondar How can I return my string type element I queued?

Comment: @Ahmn21: [`front()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/front).

Comment: @FredLarson Do I also have to call pop() to dequeue?

Comment: @Ahmn21: Yes, you need to do both. `front()` and `pop()`.

Comment: And for why you need both, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035691/why-doesnt-stdqueuepop-return-value  (short answer: exception safety)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj.front()` returns a reference to the first object in the `queue` and `obj.back()` returns a reference to the last object.

Answer (score 0):

`myfunc(obj.front())` will call your function with the first item in the queue, and `myfunc(obj.back())` will do the same with the last item in the queue.

For something like this your first reference should always be Google. A quick search yields http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/, which lists all of the functions for the a queue.

Comment: Right, and if he's using `queue.pop()` I assume the last item in the queue is what he cares about.

Comment: No `pop()` removes the *first* thing pushed. This is a queue, not a stack.

Comment: Ah whoops, wasn't thinking. My bad there.