# deque, pushing the front element to the back c++

Tags: c++, swap, deque

Im now practicing in working with data structures. And I have one question, can I write `deque.push_back(pop_front())`, if I want to swap the first and last element in the deque?

Comment: What happens when you try this out? Does it compile? Does it run?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Have you checked what `pop_back()` returns?

Comment: the `pop_back()` has no object so this code cannot compile. Besides, `pop_back()` returns the last element in the deque, not the first one. Use `std::swap` instead.

Comment: [Why doesn't std::queue::pop return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035691/why-doesnt-stdqueuepop-return-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot, sorry.
`pop_back()` has no result (`void`) so it cannot be used as a parameter
for `push_back()`.

( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_back )

It may be better to call `back()` and store the result in
a variable; then call `pop_back()`.
Repeat the same procedure with a second variable and then call
`push_back()` twice, with the first and the second variable.

---

ah?!?! the question has just changed.

The problem is the same with `pop_front()` which has a `void` result.

To swap the first and last element you can use
`std::swap(deque.front(), deque.back())`.

If you *absolutely* want to use `push/pop` functions then:

- use `back()` and memorise the value in a first variable,
- use `pop_back()`,
- use `front()` and memorise the value in a second variable,
- use `pop_front()`,
- use `push_front()` with the first variable,
- use `push_back()` with the second variable,

but this solution is much more complicated than `std::swap()`.

Of course, for all of this, you have to ensure there are enough
elements in the deque: at least one for the `std::swap()` solution,
at least two for the `push/pop` solution.

Comment: The correct member function is `back()`, not `last()`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the question, not ```push_back(pop_back())``` but ```push_back(pop_front())```

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for noticing the error. I'm so busy struggling with English that I am not as focused as I should on the code... sorry about that.